# Parsing dates from two different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have Date and timestamps in two different rows in Pandas DataFrame. Any pointer how to parse date and time together in one row which can be further used for time-series analysis further?

e.g.

```
Row 1 Date            2017-12-11 00:00:00   2017-12-11 00:00:00     2017-12-11 00:00:00     2017-12-11 00:00:00 

Row 2 Timestamp             01:00:00              02:00:00                03:00:00              04:00:00
```

and then some more rows having more data

Can Row 1 and Row 2 be combined together to have complete date/timestamp information together?

I was thinking of applying Transpose and then using parse_dates on columns. Is there any other direct way of doing that in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best is transpose `DataFrame` first for `columns` from `rows` for same dtypes per columns:

```
df = df.T
```

And then convert column `Date` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and add  `Time` converted [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

Comment: the only problem is, that there is more data in other rows. Transpose is a good idea if the dataframe holds only dates and timestamps.

Comment: @Matthias - Yes, it depends of data.

Comment: pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']) - when I am applying this to my dataframe after transpose, it is throwing below errors: any suggestions to get rid of this?                                                          TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: @Mandy - How working `pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str))` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with time series data, I strongly suggest you make the `datetime` component your index. You may find operations more efficient when your dataframe has an index containing non-duplicated values.

Your idea of transposing the dataframe first is good. Here's a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-12-11 00:00:00', '2017-12-11 00:00:00',
                    '2017-12-11 00:00:00', '2017-12-11 00:00:00'],
                   ['01:00:00', '02:00:00', '03:00:00', '04:00:00'],
                   [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
                  index=['Date', 'Timestamp', 'Data1', 'Data2'])

df = df.T
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Timestamp'))
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
print(df)

                    Data1 Data2
2017-12-11 01:00:00     1     5
2017-12-11 02:00:00     2     6
2017-12-11 03:00:00     3     7
2017-12-11 04:00:00     4     8
```

You now have a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
print(df.index)

DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-11 01:00:00', '2017-12-11 02:00:00',
               '2017-12-11 03:00:00', '2017-12-11 04:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: pd.to_timedelta works fine with your sample code but when I am using it with my dataframe data after transposing it is throwing TypeError: TypeError: object of type 'datetime.time' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                any idea how to avoid this error?

Comment: pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].astype(str)) works for me